# Почему Visual Studio 2017 не видит класс из другого проекта, находящегося в одной папке?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Скажем, есть такая структура:

```
- SimpleSolution
|--apps (folder)
|--core (folder)
  |--DataAccess (project)
    |--DataAccessPolicy.cs
  |--Domain (project)
    |--Development.cs
```

Я добавил ссылку на Domain в DataAccess, указал в файле DataAccessPolicy.cs `using SimpleSolution.Domain`, но при этом, в данном файле студия подчеркивает все классы из Domain, а также в `using SimpleSolution.Domain` **Domain**. Скажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

Comment: А вы наводить пробовали на красные строки? Что пишет и что предлагает студия? Может необходимый вам класс приватный?

Comment: В `Visual Studio 2017` не стоит добавлять ссылку другого проекта "вручную". Просто создай экземпляр класса в нужный проект и он сам предлагает добавит ссылку. Если ты всё же сделал это посмотри на `namespace` и доступ классов (`public`,`private`...)

Comment: Классы открытые, при наведении на класс Development пишет `The type or namespace name 'Development' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Ииии `и что предлагает студия` ? Обычно она помогает добавить ссылку/namespace и др. Вы можете сделать самодостаточный пример, что бы мы могли проверить это у себя?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ предлагает создать данный класс, добавить ссылку на Domain (но при этом ничего не происходит)

Comment: Необходимо добавить ссылку на Assembly в список Reference

Comment: @АртёмПрокудин Помогло, спасибо...когда добавил через references, а через проект почему то не получалось

Comment: К чему тогда `Я добавил ссылку на Domain в DataAccess` в вопросе... Только в заблуждение ввело.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я через проект в референсы добавлял, надо было по-другому

Comment: @dexploizer "через проект" - это вообще как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько причин такого поведения:

> 1. Вы не подключили ссылку на проект Domain в проекте DataAccess
> 2. Не добавили пространство имен из проекта Domain в файле .cs проекта DataAccess
> 3. Классы проекта Domain имеют модификатор доступа internal(по умолчанию) или ниже.
> 4. Версии фреймворка в проектах DataAccess и Domain не совпадают или являются не допустимыми для взаимодействия.
> 5. Студия зависла(перезапуск студии, переустановка ОС)